# has_many :through association error 'could not find the source association'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models: user, guideline and favourite_guideline (the purpose being to that a user can create his own list of favourite guidelines).

I'm getting an association error when trying to add a favourite

> ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError in
>   GuidelinesController#favourite
>   Could not find the source association(s) :favourite or :favourites in
>   model FavouriteGuideline. Try 'has_many :favourites, :through =>
>   :favourite_guidelines, :source => '. Is it one of :guideline or
>   :user?

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_many :guidelines
      has_many :favourite_guidelines
      has_many :favourites, through: :favourite_guidelines

    end

    class Guideline < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :user
      has_many :favourite_recipes
      has_many :favourited_by, through: :favourite_recipes, source: :user

    end

    class FavouriteGuideline < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :guideline
      belongs_to :user

    end
```

My favourites action in the guidelines controller is:

```
def favourite
    type = params[:type]
    if type == "favourite"
      current_user.favourites << @guideline
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'You favourited #{@guideline.name}'

    elsif type == "unfavourite"
      current_user.favourites.delete(@guideline)
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Unfavourited #{@guideline.name}'

    else
      # Type missing, nothing happens
      redirect_to :back, notice: 'Nothing happened.'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok,

> Try 'has_many :favourites, :through => :favourite_guidelines, :source => '. Is it one of :guideline or :user?

It is :guideline.

```
has_many :favourites, through: :favourite_guidelines, source: :guideline
```

> :source
>   Specifies the source association name used by has_many :through queries. Only use it if the name cannot be inferred from the association. has_many :subscribers, :through => :subscriptions will look for either :subscribers or :subscriber on Subscription, unless a :source is given.

from [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) :)

Comment: thanks - this is still giving the same error message.  I note the error title is 'ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError in GuidelinesController#favourite' - I have copied the favourite action into my question above in case it's a problem with that...